# Discord.py invites_from not returning list as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to create a command to list all of the invites created by a user (including how many uses each link has) and return a total in chat. But from my current code all I get back is:

```
<generator object Client.invites_from at 0x7f877ecc5780>
```

Here is my code to see where I am going wrong:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

bot = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Connected!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "!inv":
        server = message.channel.server.id
        invites = bot.invites_from(server)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, invites)

client.run("TOKEN")
```

If I try to loop through the returned generator I get the following error:

```
    for i in invites:
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 2693, in invites_from
    data = yield from self.http.invites_from(server.id)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Thanks a lot for any help in advance

Comment: i don't know discord API, but you can see in the error line that the method `invites_from` ask for an `id` attribute, from a `server` object. Try doing this : `server = message.channel.server` ?

Comment: message.channel.server returns the name of the server, adding .id on the end does return the correct server ID. I have also tried adding server_obj = client.get_server(server) which returns "None", when I change invites_from to use server_obj it returns:

<generator object Client.invites_from at 0x7f3be8359728>

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be with this line in `on_message()`, as pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153414/discord-py-invites-from-not-returning-list-as-expected#comment-83285680):

```
server = message.channel.server.id
```

The traceback indicates that the discord.py library is trying to use the `id` attribute of the server you pass it; currently, you're passing it the ID, but you probably need to pass the whole server object.

IOW, do this instead:

```
server = message.channel.server
```

Since `invites_from` is a coroutine, you'll also need to `await` it:

```
invites = await bot.invites_from(server)
```

Comment: When I change it that just returns the servers name, I tried printing everything out using it and I get the same results. According to the docs, get_server() required an ID which server = message.channel.server.id does provide. Also invites_from() requires a server which I'm assuming means an object as it would otherwise say ID.

Comment: Having found [the docs for `invites_from`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.invites_from), they also say this: "This function is a coroutine." Can you try doing `invites = await bot.invites_from(server)` as well?

Comment: Just tried with:

`server = message.channel.server
invites = await bot.invites_from(server)
await client.send_message(message.channel, invites)`

Now getting a HTTPException:

`File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 200, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: UNAUTHORIZED (status code: 401): 401: Unauthorized`

I appreciate the help so far, thank you

Comment: Stick the whole traceback in a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it, it was that I had client and bot the wrong way around so the bot couldn't provide the token to the API, Thanks for all the help everyone